# How to quickly get a MVC 4 w/LocalDb into Azure Web Site/Azure SQL DB ?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

This should be simple..

I have done this.

1. Create default MVC 4 template and publish site to Azure web site. No problem.
2. Create a Contact model
3. Create a view/controller and for the model. Now basic CRUD works on the site with the localDB
4. Enable migrations, add migration, create test data in seed and update migration. Everything works locally. great!

Now how do I get that database into SQL Azure?  I thought it was..

1. Publish and set ContactContext to SQL Azure string. Test connection. Works. Check 'Use this connection at runtime' .( I assume that means when it is copied it will use that connection).. So now I publish.. then goto /Contacts ... it should automatically create the new DB in Azure... but instead I get

Invalid object name 'dbo.Contacts'.

Where did I go wrong ? Is there another way.. Should I just make a script with schema and data and run that on my SQL Azure table instead?  I could do that but it seems the 'publish' way would be easier..

Answer (score 1):

When publishing, check your publish settings and see if it executes the code-first migrations.

This fixed it form me ;)